# Docker-Compose : Multiple services from local images with the same Dockerfile

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I have two services , each in its on folder : one folder called `employees-service` and another called `clients-service`.

Also , I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file and a `Dockerfile` , in the same path.

The folder structure is :

[image]

And the docker-compose is :

```
version: "3"
services:
  employees_srv:
    container_name: EmployeesContainer
    build: 
      context: ./employees-service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      
  clients_srv:
    container_name: ClientsContainer
    build:
      context: ./clients-service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
```

When I hit `docker-compose up` I get :

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.employees-service: 'dockerfile'
Unsupported config option for services.clients_srv: 'dockerfile'
```

How can I run the services with the same Dockerfile ?

Comment: What is the content of the directories `employees-service` and `clients-service`? Are there required at build time by the `Dockerfile`. I think the aim of the `dockerfile` configuration is to use an alternate `Dockerfile` lying in the same directory (for example if you add `Dockerfile-employees` and `Dockerfile-clients` in the same dir) and so it's relative to the `context` dir. The `context` dir being the context that is sent to the Docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context)

- `context`: build context that is sent to the Docker daemon.
- `dockerfile`: alternate `Dockerfile` (if the build has to use a file different from `Dockerfile` in the `context` dir).

I do not understand if those directories (`employees-service` and `clients-service`) are required at **build time** by the `Dockerfile`.
If it's the case I don't know how the build will work in the same way with one directory or the other.

If you want to make one of those directories available at **run time** you should have a look at [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes).

```
version: "3"
services:
  employees_srv:
    container_name: EmployeesContainer
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - ./employees-service:/target/in_the_container
      
  clients_srv:
    container_name: ClientsContainer
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    volumes:
      - clients-service:/target/in_the_container
```